# All rising exceptions when uploading a file to the server

Tags: c#, server

I am using the following function in order to send to a server data from Unity project:

```
public void UploadFile(string filepath)
{
 // Get an instance of WebClient
 WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
 // parse the ftp host and file into a uri path for the upload
 Uri uri = new Uri(m_FtpHost + new FileInfo(filepath).Name);
 // set the username and password for the FTP server
 client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(m_FtpUsername, m_FtpPassword);
 // upload the file asynchronously, non-blocking.
 client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", filepath);
}
```

What I want is to find all the possible exception that I could catch when I am uploading files to a server. Is there any list or tutorial about that?
EDIT: two important issues I want to handle is internet connection and problems with storage (insufficient space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it documented in the method that you're using, [`WebClient.UploadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144233(v=vs.110).aspx)?

### Exceptions

- `ArgumentNullException`: The address parameter is null -or- The fileName parameter is `null`.
- `WebException`: The `URI` formed by combining `BaseAddress` and address is invalid. -or-
  `fileName` is null, is Empty, contains invalid character, or the specified path to the file does not exist.
  -or-
  An error occurred while opening the stream.
  -or-
  There was no response from the server hosting the resource.
  -or-
  The Content-type header begins with multipart.

The [`WebException.Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status(v=vs.110).aspx)is set to indicate the error.

Comment: What about issues with internet connection or storage problems?

Comment: @snakeplissken: and `OutOfMemoryException`, `IOException` and hundreds of possible other exceptions which could be thrown? They are not directly related and could always be raised. You could catch `Exception`